# Como aplicar cor ao conteúdo de um elemento?

Tags: css, html5

Imaginando o cenário HTML:

```html
<div>
    <a>Cachorro</a>
    <p>Leão</p>
    Macaco
    <i>Gaivota</i>
</div>
```

Eu preciso aplicar um estilo específico para `Macaco`, sem afetar os elementos adjacentes ou precisar invalidar eles.

Atualmente, consigo o resultado desejado da seguinte forma:

```css
div>* {
  color: initial;
}

div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>Cachorro</a>
  <p>Leão</p>
  Macaco
  <i>Gaivota</i>
</div>
```

Mas não quero ter que reverter as alterações para elementos filhos de `<div>` e sim aplicar exclusivamente em `Macaco`, sem ter que invalidar outros elementos no mesmo nível como a primeira regra do exemplo acima.

Como posso aplicar a cor vermelha exclusivamente ao `Macaco`, sem ter que colocar o mesmo dentro de um elemento e sem ter que selecionar elementos adjacentes, apenas utilizando CSS?

Comment: Não existe, até tivemos documentado a implementação `:contains()`, ha um bom tempo atrás, mas não está mais disponível. Hoje o máximo que temos é o [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) e que não resolve.

Comment: Se não entendi errado!!!... sim é possível, já vi algo assim no **front-end**  sem usar um elemento filho. acho que é chamado de **pseudo-classe**  ... se for isso é tbm  conhecida como **pseudo-elementos**

Comment: no css ficaria dessa forma `a::before {
    content: "Esse é um gato";
   
}`  ou   **a::before**       e no js teria essa sintaxe `document.querySelector("a").textContent `

Comment: Esse tal **pseudo-elementos**  é mais usados para adicionar algo antes ou depois do elemento que precisa e tbm usado para pegar um texto .

Comment: apenas para entender melhor, para quê precisa do texto? é que o CSS é usado para formatar o layout e não alterar, normalmente o conteúdo se altera com `javascript`, por isso fiquei curioso de entender.. aliás, por *"selecionar o texto do elemento"* você quer dizer, saber se tem o texto lá, ou para mudar o conteúdo?

Comment: Estou fugindo um pouco da pergunta, a qual já tem uma resposta bem satisfatória, mas por que haveria a necessidade de escrever _Macaco_ sem utilizar `tag`s?

Comment: @Heinrich, em documentos HTML produzido por autômatos, XLST, bibliotecas de conversão, programadores iniciantes ou testes empíricos, podem produzir conteúdo nas mais variadas formas. Então na criação de frameworks um parser de HTML embutido deve ser capaz de analisar qualquer entrada válida, mesmo que não seja trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não existe meio de selecionar textos com CSS, o máximo que temos (e que não atendem o caso) são os seletores:

## `::first-letter`

Seleciona a primeira letra

```css
.foobar::first-letter {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="foobar">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sagittis, odio non efficitur tristique, ipsum tortor semper urna, vel ultricies ipsum leo sit amet risus.
</div>

<div class="foobar">
Curabitur finibus sagittis sapien nec tempus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Morbi ultrices elit ac velit pellentesque egestas.
</div>
```

## `::first-line`

Seleciona a primeira linha, **se o texto tiver quebra automática** o estilo só será aplicado até antes do texto quebrar

```css
.foobar::first-line {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="foobar">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sagittis, odio non efficitur tristique, ipsum tortor semper urna, vel ultricies ipsum leo sit amet risus.

</div>

<div class="foobar">


Curabitur finibus sagittis sapien nec tempus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Morbi ultrices elit ac velit pellentesque egestas.
</div>
```

Então para concluir, até o momento nem sugestão de implementação para tal existe, o melhor mesmo é simplesmente criar um elemento inline (como span) com class ou id (depende do caso) e aplicar o estilo aonde desejar, simplesmente assim:

```
<div>
  <a>Cachorro</a>
  <p>Leão</p>
  <span class="exclusivo">Macaco</span>
  <i>Gaivota</i>
</div>
```

E não precisa de JavaScript para isso nem nada exagerado, a não ser que seja algo muito dinâmico mesmo, porque se for o caso, ai você poderia até aplicar um `<span class="excluiso">...</span>` antes mesmo da página ser baixada, ou seja, no "back-end", mas isso seria um pouco mais além.

Answer (score -7):

Creio que o que vc deseja é fazer isso

```js
let element = document.getElementById("myElement");
let text = element.textContent;
console.log(text);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="myElement">ESSE TEXTO</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Com JS ok, mas acho que a pergunta é voltada somente para o CSS, sobre como atingir o resultado apenas com codigo CSS. Inclusive seu HTML nem representa a mesma ideia da pergunta.

Comment: Ata, agora entendi, mas a sua pergunta está incompleta, você pede ajuda para acessar o texto mas não especifica se tem que ser obrigatoriamente com css
De qualquer forma, não tem como não. Para isso vc realmente tem que usar uma tag html.

Comment: Olá Christian. Boas-vindas ao site. As tags na pergunta indicam as tecnologias relevantes ao problema -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/L81FF.png, o autor da pergunta está solicitando [tag:css] e [tag:html5] -- Segue as instruções da Central De Ajuda do Stack Overflow em Português: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging. *Agradecemos a compreensão*.

Comment: Ata de boas então, peço perdão, não me atentei a isso.